# insert the value from variable python msqldb

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import MySQLdb

    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","project_one" )
    ahg="dfas223d";
    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    #sql = """INSERT INTO emloyee(string_one)VALUES ('Mac424234')"""
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute("insert into emloyee(string_one) values(%s)",ahg)
    # Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM emloyee")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
    print (row)

    db.close()
```

this is the code which have error
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\gatim project\module2\module4\modle4.py", line 13, in 
  cursor.execute("insert into emloyee(string_one) values(%s)",ahg)
  File "C:\Users\Raswanth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 203, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

***************I find the answer
cursor.execute("insert into emloyee(string_one) values('%s')"%(ahg))****

Comment: The arguments have to be a tuple or list: `cursor.execute("insert into emloyee(string_one) values(%s)", [ahg])`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `ahg` is defined, but as @Klaus D. indicates, you need to provide a `list` of arguments to that, not a single definition.

By writing `cursor.execute("insert into emloyee(string_one) values(%s)",ahg)`, you are only plugging in ONE value, `ahg`, which is not what `values(%s)` is trying to do. The `values(%s)` is expecting to iterate through a number of values, not one, so `ahg` needs to be a list.

@Klaus D. suggestion of `cursor.execute("insert into emloyee(string_one) values(%s)", [ahg])` would accomplish that.